GDB Undefined info command: "bt"
I wrote a while loop in GDB to print all threads' backtrace except for thread 306 and 310.
set $thr_count = 327
set $i = 1
while $i <= $thr_count
  if $i != 310 && $i != 306
    thread apply $i bt
  end
  set $i = $i + 1
end

However, the GDB says Undefined info command: "bt".  Try "help info".

That error message would seem to indicate you actually wrote info bt -- note the "Undefined info command:".  I tried your code in a fresh GDB session and it works fine for me (GDB 14.1).
